# Teechart, Gantt Series, Visual Studio's Designer And The "Array rank '2' is too high" Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, teechart

Everytime I try to save changes to a `UserControl` that contains a chart using gantt series, Visual Studio's designer always pops up the following error message:

> Array rank '2' is too high. visual studio can only load and save arrays with rank 1.

I'm compiling against Teechart for .Net 2012 4.1.2012.* and I think it has something todo with this property

```
[Description("MultiDimensional array to store Multiple NextTasks, with the indices being start and end task index and the value -1.")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public double[,] MultipleNextTasks
```

of class `Gantt`, but I can't imagine that this slipped the devs. What I can do is opening the code editor, then close the visual designer and simply save via the editor to persist my changes, but this is a very unsatisfying solution.

Does anyone know how to fix this permanently?

Comment: Hello,

I can not reproduce your problem using last version of TeeChartfor.Net build number 4.1.2012.01312. Would be very grateful if you can arrange for us a simple project, because we can reproduce your problem exactly here. Moreover, If you can tell us which version of TeeChartFor.Net are you using, would be very helpful for us, too. 

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @SandraPazos I'm using TeeChartFor.Net 4.1.2012.5102 with Visual Studio 2010 and I have arranged the simple project you asked for: [link](http://db.tt/UbMvKzUR) In the Screenshots folder you'll find a screenshot of the error message that pops up as soon as I hit ctrl+s to save changes. Thanks,

Comment: Hello NullAndVoid, Many thanks for your attached example and image. I can reproduce this problem using last version of TeeChartFor.Net build number 4.1.2012.01310. I have added it in bug list report with number[TF02016535] and we will try to fix it to upcoming versions of TeeChartFor.Net.
Thanks,

Comment: Great! Thanks for your efforts. Could you do me a favor and formulate your comment as a proper answer, that I can accept and maybe up-vote my question, since it's a valid bug report. So this whole incident is handled stackoverflow-style ;) Best Regards,

Comment: Ok, I already do  it. :D
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for your attached example and image. I can reproduce this problem using last version of TeeChartFor.Net build number 4.1.2012.01310. I have added it in bug list report with number [**TF02016534**] and we will try to fix it to upcoming versions of TeeChartFor.Net.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello @NullAndVoid, first I apologize, so,  I have made a mistake when write the number of bug and I  have realized now, sorry. Therefore, the bug TF02016535 is incorrect, the correct bug number is TF02016534.  On the other hand,the bug isn't still fixed but I have increased its severity, because we try to fix it to upcoming versions of TeeChartFor.Net.